# Handling queue messages (for example, JMS in WebLogic) depending to each other on cluster systems

Tags: jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, bpel, osb, oracle-soa

I am developing a SOA system which handles messages came from external systems. The external messages come in exact order how they should be. The problem arises on my handling system part. For example, I am having messages message_1, message_2, message_3, message_4. All messages except message_1 depend on message_1. But since messages are processed asynchronously, there are cases where message_2 or message_3 are performed before message_1. These cases include heavy tasks including access to DB, so there may be multiple delays before finishing the execution. Also, these tasks are performed on cluster systems. So the problem becomes even wider when installed on these systems. However, the good news is the message queue system (in our case JMS) is one for all cluster systems, that is global.

So the question is:
Is there any good use cases or solutions for such problems of handling dependent to each other messages or data on cluster or asynchronous systems? Maybe there are solutions with locking any resource (file, db or ejb/lock object)? or locking JMS message?

Used technologies are:
Oracle SOA Suite with BPEL, Java EE 6, Oracle OSB, Oracle WebLogic 10.3 with JMS, Oracle DB 11g, JDeveloper 11.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mediator to resequence the message, here is a link to right section of the oracle developers guide http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10224/med_resequencer.htm